gitlab-ci: use external docker image to test project
first of all, i am new to the gitlab ci scene, so i am sorry for asking bad questions.
i have a repository which i want to test with a gitlab runner. for this i have created another project and build a docker image. this image is pushed to a registry which is accessable to the gitlab runner.
my dockerfile looks something like this:
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update \
    && apk add python3 py3-pip \
    && apk add make cmake gcc g++ \
    && mkdir app \
    && mkdir repo/

COPY ["requirements.txt", "/app/requirements.txt"]
COPY ["src/", "app/"]

WORKDIR "/app/"
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]

my gitllab-ci looks something like this:
stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - mkdir -p /tmp/
  - docker pull dockerimage:latest

build-repo:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker run -v $(pwd):/repo/ dockerimage:main [ARGUMENTS]

basically, i want to start up a docker container inside the gitlab pipeline. this container has a python script which should get arguments passed from the gitlab-ci file. the script inside the container then builds the project and initialises the testing. for this, the repository is being mounted to the container.
now to my problem. the thing i seem to not being able to wrap my head around is the parameter passing part. locally, this works fine when i run the container but not in the pipeline. there the following error arises:
Tester: error: unrecognized arguments: sh if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then
    exec /bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /bin/sh ]; then
    exec /bin/sh 
elif [ -x /busybox/sh ]; then
    exec /busybox/sh 
else
    echo shell not found
    exit 1
fi

to me it looks like the container got a shell script passed, which does not really make sense to me. i tryed altering the running of the container, also tryed to just run the python script inside the container but this did way worse than the current form.
if someone might have an idea what i did wrong or may have a better solution for my intend, feedback is very welcome.
Edit: here is the contents of my toml file:
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runner"
  url = "..."
  id = 62
  token = "..."
  token_obtained_at = 2024-04-13T08:36:43Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "customimage:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0

running a simple echo hello world does not work, somehow i still get the same error.

Your gitlab-runner is not configured properly. The docker image your gitlab runner runs is not valid. How did you configure it? Why not specify image: docker? Where do you expect to connect to docker daemon from inside the shell running inside your pipeline?

i configured the runner with docker executor and mapped the docker.sock to the container, so the gitlab runner should have access to the machines docker server.
i had it specify image: docker at some point, but i can not give you a good reason why i did not change it back.
the error "Tester: error: unrecognized arguments: ..." is being printed by the python script inside the tester container. for me it looks like the startup of the containers are working.

Please post the /etc/gitlab/runner.toml config. The script you posted is in gitlab runner source code https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/main/shells/bash.go#L17 . I suspect your configuration us not valid. Does a simple echo hello world work on your runner?
